# How to write Arabic maad sign in latex?

Tags: xetex, symbols, arabic

I would like to get :

[image]

Is there any code to get it?

Comment: Do you know unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) to it?

Comment: Is it the same symbol of this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596532/problem-with-arabic-characters-sakin-dopesh-and-maad-in-latex

Comment: Do you mean `U+0653`, usually called *maddah* in English-speaking circles? How do you intend to compile your document?

Comment: Isn't this the ʿalāmat al-ḥāšiyah for marginal annotations? If so, the corresponding unicode code point is `U+0602`. Example: ؂

Comment: I didn't pay attention, it's the maddah. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking for a Unicode non-breaking space (U+00A0} with a combining maddah above (U+0653).

Here is a solution in LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelprovide[import=ar, onchar=fonts ids]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\newcommand\spacingmaddah{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{^^^^00a0^^^^0653}}

\begin{document}
Hello Maddah, {\spacingmaddah}

Hello Faddah.  ٓ
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus Serif/Amiri sample]

You can change the fonts and the default language to your liking.

It would mostly work, with small modifications, in XeLaTeX.  `bidi=basic` would need to become `bidi=default`, and you would remove `\usepackage{microtype}` and `onchar=fonts ids`.  The disadvantage is that the document would no longer automatically switch to the Arabic font and hyphenation when it sees Arabic writing.  You would need to put `\foreignlanguage{arabic}` and `\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}` tags everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to approach Arabic in LaTeX. Since you're using the `xetex` engine, you may like the `arabxetex` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
This is \textit{maddah:} \textarab[utf]{ٓ}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(Unfortunately, the code doesn’t show up very clearly, at least not with the fonts my browser uses, where the *maddah* looks like a smudge on the `}`. To explain, between the `{}` I’ve simply typed `U+0653`, using an editor which accepts such input. You should be able to copy and paste my code despite the problem with display.)

Comment: The code I used in my answer for readability, `^^^^00a0^^^^0653`, also works in XeTeX.

Comment: @Davislor StackExchange’s switch to system fonts is not without problems, it seems.